# How to remove whitespaces from text except space

Tags: java

In project I get data from external API and use it for creating PDF.
Unfortunatelly here are some whitespaces that broke pdf template, like `U+200B`.
I try to fix it

```
private String repair(String text) {
        return text == null ? "" : text.stripLeading().stripTrailing().replaceAll("[^\\S ]", "");
    }
```

but it doesn't help.
How to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve with replaceAll("[\p{Cf}]", "")